# Collection View is skipping one row When using scrolltoindexpath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am using the collection view and i am trying to make infinite scrolling in collection view using the following method:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    if (infoArray.count-1 == self.indexPathForVisibleCells.row) {

        [self.collection_View scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];    //     [self.collection_View scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]  atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];

    }
     }
```

When i am using this method, when it comes at last cell and then it moves to the cell with index 1 not to the cell with index 0. Can someone explain this behaviour and give a possible solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

you must try this-

[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] 
                            atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop
                                    animated:YES];

for more please refer following link-
http://www.tuicode.com/question/58707ef3c116a36d35c56c21

Comment: Already tried this also. It is not working with any other than scrollposiitonnone

Comment: then please add following line [collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

Comment: Also tried this. Not scrolling to index 0. It is staying at current visible index.

Comment: have you try these lines of code . [collectionView setScrollsToTop:YES]; or collectionView.contentOffset.x = 0
or [collectionView setScrollsToTop];

Comment: Ok wait trying it now.

Comment: none of these work. I have tried all, i think there is something else also. I have disabled Prefetching also.I am checking out the link for now.

Comment: actually i am using Paging with collection so i think content offset will not work.

Comment: please refer this link hope you get your solution -
 https://rolandleth.com/uicollectionview-snap-scrolling-and-pagination